# Show tooltip on DIV FOCUS and HOVER on it

Tags: css, angular, tooltip

I am displaying a tooltip on an input field using css and surrounding the inPut within DIV. Basically the style is applying on DIV. The style gets applied on hover of the input field now.I want to display the tooltip as soon as the user tabs into that field. I see that DIV doesn't work on :focus. Any thoughts on how to show as soon as user focus on the field. I am using angular, can we apply some the class of the parentNode or any other way of doing it.

```js
test(e: Event) {    
  if (this.inputfield.nativeElement.parentNode.tagName.toString().toLowerCase() === 'div') {
    // apply the class to the parentNode
  }
}
```

```css
.tooltipmain {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltipmain .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 185px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltipmain .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}

.tooltipmain:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltipmain">
   <input #inputfield onFocus="test($event)"> </input>
   <div class="tooltiptext">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please use stackblitz?

Comment: @Asanka, Please find the link https://angular-eqvu8v.stackblitz.io/     On mouse over that textinput, you can see a table displayed with just 'TTTT' in it. I want the same table to be shown, when user focus into the textinput using tab

Comment: Do you satisfy with S.Honderdos's answer?

Comment: @Asanka, yes I would

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `focus`, `blur`, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to track events triggered by the input field. Each of these events will be calling a function which will update the `isFocussed` variable.

```
<input
    (blur)="focusChanged(false)"
    (focus)="focusChanged(true)"
    (mouseenter)="focusChanged(true)"
    (mouseleave)="focusChanged(false)"
    type="text">
```

On the element you want to toggle visibility you can make use of `[class.<className>="<expression>"]`. This will add/remove a class on the element based on the expressions.

```
<div [class.isActive]="focussed" class="tooltiptext">
```

[Stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vckyyq)

Comment: @Honderdos, this seems to be a perfect solution

Comment: @Honderdos, will it be possible to set a tabindex in each TD's , assuming there are one or more rows, when tooltip is shown, the screen reader can read the data in the tooltip

Comment: It is agains standards to focus on the tooltip. [this](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/accessible-tooltips/) might help